# Safely using String for passwords by using reflection to scrub contents prior to garbage collection

Tags: java, string, security, garbage-collection, passwords

Does using reflection to scrub a `String` make using `String` as safe as using `char[]` for passwords?

From a security aspect, it is generally considered best practice to use `char[]` for storing/passing passwords, because one can zero-out its contents as soon as possible in code, which may be significantly before garbage collection cleans it up and the memory is reused (wiping all trace), limiting the window of time for a memory attack.

However, `char[]` is not as convenient as `String`, so it would be handy if one could "scrub" a `String` if needed, thus making `String` as safe as `char[]`.

Below is a method that uses reflection to zero-out the fields of `String`.

Is this method "OK", and does it achieve the goal of making `String` as safe as `char[]` for passwords?

```
public static void scrub(String str) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field valueField = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    Field offsetField = String.class.getDeclaredField("offset");
    Field countField = String.class.getDeclaredField("count");
    Field hashField = String.class.getDeclaredField("hash");
    valueField.setAccessible(true);
    offsetField.setAccessible(true);
    countField.setAccessible(true);
    hashField.setAccessible(true);
    char[] value = (char[]) valueField.get(str);
    // overwrite the relevant array contents with null chars
    Arrays.fill(value, offsetField.getInt(str), countField.getInt(str), '\0');
    countField.set(str, 0); // scrub password length too
    hashField.set(str, 0); // the hash could be used to crack a password
    valueField.setAccessible(false);
    offsetField.setAccessible(false);
    countField.setAccessible(false);
    hashField.setAccessible(false);
}
```

Here's a simple test:

```
String str = "password";
scrub(str);
System.out.println('"' + str + '"');
```

Output:

```
""
```

**Note:** You may assume that passwords are not `String` constants and thus calling this method will have no adverse effect on interned Strings.

Also, I have left the method is a fairly "raw" state for simplicity's sake. If I were to use it, I would not declare exceptions thrown (try/catch/ignoring them) and refactor repeated code.

Comment: Well, it seems to zero out the chars, but isn't that quite dependent on the JVM implementation?

Comment: memory snooping? that's a fantasy attack. why not worry about something more realistic, like NSA snooping your network traffic.

Comment: Screams "undefined behavior" at me. Good luck with dragons, velociraptors and black holes :)

Comment: Your code depends on the implementation of the String class. And it happens that the Oracle JDK/openJDK from version 7u6 have a different implementation and your `scrub` method would throw an exception.

Comment: A good implementation of `String` wont have offset. You ought to be a bit more robust (not something that really happens with most reflection code). / "Memory snooping" isn't an entirely unrealistic attack, particularly when you consider swapping/hibernation may place data on physical medium for a surprising length of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two potential safety concerns:

1. The String may share its backing array with other Strings; e.g. if the `String` was created by calling `substring` on a larger `String`.  So when you zero the entire `value` array you *could* be overwriting the state of other strings ... that don't contain passwords.

   The cure is to only zero the part of the backing array that is used by the password string.
2. The JLS ([17.5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3)) warns that the effects of using reflection to change `final` variables is undefined.

   However, the context for this is the Java Memory Model, and the fact that the compiler is allowed to aggressively cache `final` variables.  In this case:

   - you would expect the String to be thread-confined, and
   - you shouldn't be using any of those variables again.

I wouldn't expect either of these to be *real* problems ... modulo fixing the over-aggressive zeroing of `value`.

---

But the real concern is [Velociraptors](http://xkcd.com/292/).  :-)

---

I'm puzzled that you would actually bothering to zap passwords like this.  When you think about it, what you are protecting against is the possibility that someone can read process memory ... or a core dump or swap file ... to retrieve passwords.  But if someone can do that, your system security has to have already been compromised ... cos' those things most likely require `root` access (or equivalent).  And if they have `root` access they can "debug" your program and catch the passwords *before* your application zaps them.

Comment: Perhaps the code is overly brutal/simple. What if only the section of the array pointed to was wiped? And only the count set to zero (to remove trace of how long the password is)?

Comment: The major concern, security, is unaffected by this concern. A string could be observed as broken after resetting.

Comment: OK - I've edited the code to only scrub the section of the array actually being used.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - it depends.  If think that security trumps all other concerns (including correct function of the application) then I guess it doesn't matter if the password zapper trashes other strings too.  Otherwise ... you should at least *consider* this.

Comment: I see what you mean -- my comment wasn't about the issue with structural sharing. But another, related danger is lurking: using reflection you commit yourself to a particular String implementation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - true, though if the (private) representation used by String changed, the most likely result would be a reflection exception in the zapper.

Answer (score 1):

One argument I have against String is that it's just too easy to inadvertently make a copy. Using strings safely is possible in theory, but the whole library ecosystem is based on the assumption that it's perfectly OK to copy strings. In the end, considering all the restrictions, strings may not be as convenient for this use case as they generally are.

Comment: But one can copy `char[]` too. Although your point is valid, the coding disipline around passwords should be tightly reviewed to ensure copies are not made, regardless of the type.